# How to inject a html element to the Dom using service in angular4?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i am using angular4, and currently i have a scenario where i have to create a global loader when i fetch some data using observables. my thought was to create a loader html and render it on the dom and then clean it on success and error.

how can i dump my loader html using service and it will become a global loader

```
//dump a loader html
this.http.get('controller/nmethod').subscribe(success => {
        //clear the loader html
    }, error => {
        //clear the loader html
    }, () => {
        //clear the loader html
    })
```

Comment: You set a flag of your component to true, to display the loader, and set it to false to hide it. In the tamplete, you put *ngIf="flag" on the loader.

Comment: Why do not you use local `subscribe` in `component`, and use `ngBusy` directive.

Answer (score 0):

You are two ways to do this.

The first is to have a flag, for example isDataLoaded that you switch when the observable is in success or in error:

For the demo:

**The component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  isDataLoaded: boolean = false
  data: string = ""

  constructor() {
    this.loadData()
  }

  showResult() {
    this.loadData()
  }

  private loadData() {
    this.isDataLoaded = false
    Observable.of("data is loaded")
      .delay(1000)
      .subscribe(
        succes => {
          this.isDataLoaded = true
          this.data = succes
        },
        err => {
          this.isDataLoaded = true
          this.data = err
        }
      )
  }
}
```

**The component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded; else loading">
  {{data}}
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</ng-template>

<button (click)="showResult()">Show result</button>
```

---

Or use the observable to check if it's finished:

**The componet.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  data2$: Observable<string>

  constructor() {
    this.loadData2()
  }

  showResult() {
    this.loadData2()
  }

  private loadData2() {
    this.data2$ = Observable.of("data 2 is loaded").delay(3000)
  }
}
```

**The component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="data2$ | async; let data2; else loading2">
  {{data2}}
</div>
<ng-template #loading2>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</ng-template>

<button (click)="showResult()">Show result</button>
```

The full demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lv66zw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

The first option can be use if you do others actions when the observable is finished

The second option is shorter and you can use it if you do nothing in callbacks